# Find if a multivariable function converges to a limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

So the function is given as: $$\lim_{x \to m \\ y \to d} \frac{\ln(x-m+e)^{y-d}}{\sqrt{(x-m+1)^2+(y-d)^2-1}} \\ 1) \lim_{x=m \\ y \to d}\frac{\ln(e^{y-d})}{\sqrt{1^2+(y-d)^2-1}}=1$$ Shouldn't the limit be infinity?

2) $$\lim_{y=d \\ x\to m}\frac{\ln(x-m+1)}{\sqrt{(x-m+1)-1}}=\left[\frac{0}{0} \right] \neq 0 \Rightarrow \neg \exists \,\lim $$

I don't understand how this works, why, if those limits are not equal, the limit doesn't exist. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

Denote with $f(x,y)$ the function.
Then
$$f(m,y)=\frac{y-d}{|y-d|}$$
hence
\begin{align}
\lim_{y\to d^+}f(m,y)=1&&\lim_{y\to d^-}f(m,y)=-1
\end{align}
thus $f$ has no limit as $x\to m$ and $y\to d$.